# How to get black trim markings in memoir when having colored text?

Tags: color, memoir, crop

When I have colored text it seems that color rubs of on the trim markings when switching page. How can I make all of them black?

An example:

```
\documentclass[showtrims,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\pageav
\stockaiv
\trimFrame
\medievalpage
\setpagecc{\paperheight}{\paperwidth}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\color{red}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

(I had some trouble with making the example but at least it shows what I mean. Feel free to fix it for me if you know how to make it nicer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\trimmarkscolor{\color{black}}
```

That macro is empty by default as `memoir` does not load any color packages